# ASP.NET: checkboxlist with textbox?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm working in ASP.NET and I have a CheckBoxList where I want one of the options to be basically like "Other: **_**." So I need to include a textbox where the user can fill in their own option. It doesn't seem like there's a way to include a textbox inside of a checkboxlist, however. What's the best way to make this work?

-UPDATE-

If using a separate textbox control, how do I position it so it will align correctly with the checkbox?

Comment: playing css with firebug/developer tool open is the best self taught ever. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the textbox a separate control on the page, then in your codebehind, check to see if other is checked.  If it is, pull the value of the textbox, and use that.

**To answer the question in your edit:**  You'll have to play with the CSS of the page to get it positioned correctly.  How you do it depends on the layout of the page, among other things.  I recommend posting some of the HTML from your page in another question and ask about how to position them.

Answer (score 0):

What @Kyle Trauberman said...

> Make the textbox a separate control on
>   the page, then in your codebehind,
>   check to see if other is checked. If
>   it is, pull the value of the textbox,
>   and use that.

Plus use javascript to hide or gray out the option unless the checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
string test="";
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chk_list" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="00">xxxx</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:TextBox ID="other" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

inside the for loop

```
if (chk_list.Items[i].Value == "00")
{
    test +=chk_list.Items[i].Text + other.Text;
}
```